# Does the Casimir Effect Fluctuate?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, casimir-effect

I understand that two uncharged plates places nanometres apart experience a net force due to their interference with the quantized fields around them.

I'm wondering whether or not this force fluctuates randomly as is the case with most quantum effects, even if the average force is constant.

Comment: What do you mean "the average force is constant"? The force changes the distance, but also depends on distance itself.

Comment: I mean if we assume the distance remains constant, does the force fluctuate?